# What counts as a "Neighbor" in Conways' game of life?

Tags: terminology, recreational-mathematics, cellular-automata

I have looked everywhere but I cannot find an answer for this.

Since I am bored, I am trying to create this game, but I can't seem to figure out what is considered a "Neighbor".  Is it only directly above/below/right/left? or is it above, above and to the right, right, below and to the right, etc.?

Comment: From wikipedia: "Every cell interacts with its eight neighbours, which are the cells that are horizontally, vertically, or diagonally adjacent."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conway's Game of Life uses the 8-cell [Moore neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood), which includes the diagonal neighbors. Not all CAs use this; others use the 4-cell [Von Neumann neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood), which excludes diagonal neighbors.